# detecting if website has e-commerce in Node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, e-commerce

I need to detect programatically if a website has an e-commerce platform/system
I don't need to know which one, I just need to know if the website has one.
(I have a big list of websites so I probably need to scrape them)
any suggestions on how I could do this *without* using external websites (like rescan.io/builtwith/etc) would be greatly appreciated!
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package called Puppeteer which is used to do web-scraping in node.js.

I don't know what platforms you are trying to look for, but I guess you could try something like giving the list of websites you want to check to a node.js process and ask Puppeteer to scrape them all. Then you look at the content you get back and for example look for Shopify's CDN in the  tags or check the  tags for keywords.

You will definitely need to check each different platform like Magento or Shopify for unique source code that clearly sets apart the framework you are looking at from other tools.